# Magmi category creator does not work with options

Tags: magento-1.9, category, magmi

I am importing ~5000 products into our Magento 1.9 via Magmi 0.7.22 without major issues. The categories shall not be active so I set the is_active flag in the *categories* column to 0:

```
[myroot]/CatA1::0::1::1/CatA2::0::1::1;;[myroot]/CatB1::0::1::1/CatB2::0::1::1
```

According to the [documentation](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer#Defining_category_options) of the CategoryImporter plugin the syntax is as follows:

```
[root category]/category name::[is_active]::[is_anchor]::[include_in_menu]
```

But all categories which are created during the import are active. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I hit a known bug, which was already reported in Magmi's tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/bugs/67/

Magmi needs to remove the "position" attribute for some reason, which is separated with "::", just as the other attributes. All category attributes are optional. The bug is now that *all* attributes are removed instead of only the "position" attribute.

The code repository at SourceForge is quite inactive, so I decided to work around the bug myself in a way that I would need a different value separator for the "position" attribute (actually I don't need the positioning). In `plugins/extra/itemprocessors/categories/categoryimport.php`, I modified the `explode()` separator in line 205:

Before:

```
foreach ($pcatparts as $cp) {
    $a = explode("::", $cp);
    $catparts[] = $a[0];
    $catpos[] = (count($a) > 1 ? $a[1] : "0");
    // remove position to build catpart array
}
```

After:

```
foreach ($pcatparts as $cp) {
    $a = explode(":P:", $cp);
    $catparts[] = $a[0];
    $catpos[] = (count($a) > 1 ? $a[1] : "0");
    // remove position to build catpart array
}
```